# How can I use 2 times the same table from a SELECT query to update a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The situation here is that I have a very complex query that generates me a table with just 2 columns, one column is the column of total of products sold by a certain employee, and the other column is the id of the employee, what Im trying to do is to use this table to update N_products column of employees(Number of sold products). The already working query is:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(QUANTITY) AS productosven, 
    EmployeeID 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Orders.OrderID, Orders.EmployeeID, [Order Details].Quantity 
     FROM 
         Orders  
     INNER JOIN 
         DimEmployee ON Orders.EmployeeID = DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
     INNER JOIN 
         [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
     GROUP BY 
         EmployeeId) x
```

The table it generates is:

[image]

The query that I'm trying to implement is:

```
UPDATE DimEmployee 
SET N_Products = (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS productosven 
                  FROM
                      (SELECT 
                           Orders.OrderID, Orders.EmployeeID, [Order Details].Quantity 
                       FROM 
                           Orders  
                       INNER JOIN 
                           DimEmployee ON Orders.EmployeeID = DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
                       INNER JOIN 
                           [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID) AS X
                  GROUP BY EmployeeId)
WHERE 
    EmployeeID = (SELECT EmployeeID 
                  FROM
                      (SELECT 
                           Orders.OrderID, Orders.EmployeeID, [Order Details].Quantity 
                       FROM 
                           Orders  
                       INNER JOIN 
                           DimEmployee ON Orders.EmployeeID = DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
                       INNER JOIN 
                           [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID) AS X 
                  GROUP BY EmployeeId)
```

Basically, I'm trying to use my `SELECT` query twice, the first time is to get the products and store it in `N_products`, and the second time to compare it with the id from the same query, but the SQL Server generates an error:

> Mens. 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The subquery has returned more than one value, which is not correct when it goes after =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when it is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.  So I might recommend:

```
UPDATE e
    SET n_products = sum_quantity
FROM DimEmployee e JOIN
     (SELECT o.EmployeeID, SUM(Quantity) as sum_quantity
      FROM Orders o JOIN
           [Order Details] od
           ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
      GROUP BY o.EmployeeID
     ) o
     ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID;
```

Note that this does not update the field if there are no orders for an employee (which seems to be the intent of your query).  If you do want to update even in that case, then you could use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: What is the o and od?

Comment: Those are table aliases.  They are a very important part of the SQL language -- you can think of them as abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: But you didnt use AS, AS is not necesary?, that will work like that?

Comment: @SebasSilva . . . Definitely.  `as` is optional (in most databases) and not allowed by some (such as Oracle).  I always use `as` for column aliases and never for table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
UPDATE DimEmployee
SET N_Products = (
    SELECT sum(od.Quantity) 
    FROM Orders o INNER JOIN [Order Details] od ON od.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
    WHERE o.EmployeeID = DimEmployee.EmployeeID
);
```